# ComplexUpset: How can I plot ONLY specific intersections?

Tags: r, upsetr, complex-upset

I am trying to make an upset plot that only shows specific intersections. I have 6 different fjords which generate too many intersections. I am only interested in plotting some of those:

I have run this next script:

```
upset(fjords, fjordnames, width_ratio=0.15, height_ratio = 0.6, sort_sets=FALSE, sort_intersections = "descending", sort_intersections_by = 'cardinality',
 base_annotations = list('Intersection size'=list(aes=aes(x=intersection, fill=Classification), geom=list(geom_bar(stat = "count", position='stack'),
 theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")), scale_fill_manual(values=divpalette)))))
```

I obtained the next plot:
[Species shared by fjords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yqkf.png)

But I am only interested in showing the intersections that are marked with the red arrow. I want all the others removed. I have looked for answers but have found none. Is there a way to only select those intersections?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2):

You need to first update to a recent version (minimum recommended 1.2):

```
install.packages('ComplexUpset')
```

And then use the `intersections` argument:

```
upset(
    movies,
    genres,
    width_ratio=0.1,
    intersections=list(
        'Comedy',
        'Drama',
        c('Comedy', 'Romance'),
        c('Drama', 'Romance'),
        'Outside of known sets',
        'Action'
    )
)
```

[image]

You can keep the order by adding `sort_intersections=FALSE`.